# NOT NULL constraint failed: permission_portal_task.user_id

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User,Group,Permission
from django.utils import timezone
# Create your models here.

class Role(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=128)
    display_name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description=models.TextField()
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class Task(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    name=models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description=models.TextField(default='Description')
    approoved = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

I am not able to link the Role and task database. Getting an error "NOT NULL constraint failed: permission_portal_task.user_id"

Comment: I don't think you want unique=True on your ForeignKey.  That would imply a one to one relationship, but I am guessing you can have many tasks per user.

Comment: each user can have just one task.

Comment: its there even after removing unique=True

Comment: There is no relationship between Task and Role.

Comment: Look up one to one field: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/examples/one_to_one/#one-to-one-relationships

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
class Task(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True, blank=True, null=True)
```

set your `user` field's `null` attribute to `True`. This will remove your **NOT NULL constraint failed** error.
Also run `python manage.py makemigrations` and `python manage.py migrate` to reflect this change to your database.